Excel query when subtotalling
I have a large set of data that has clients name, product type and then premium. I want to group all the clients products together and then delete any clients where their total premium is more than 10k. Is this possible?  I have used subtotal which shows me the total premium for each client but how do I remove the ones over 10k?
Thanks
Subtotals have given me the total premium for each client but I don’t know how to delete any clients over 10k without going through each client individually and there are over 4k clients

Hi, what’s the version of Excel you’re using?

While the look of your data in unclear, the general approach to solve your task is here.
You need to use an additional column to put there a checkmark.

Add an additional column.
Using autofilter, filter rich clients.
Select cells in additional column and put checkmark there (any value).
Clear autofilter.
Sort the range by the checkmark column.
Select the marked range then select rows (Shift+Space).
Delete selected rows.


May be, you need to preserve the initial order of rows. In this case, use one more column and put there the numeration prior starting the procedure above. At the end, sort the range by this numeration and delete the column.

To keep filtered records according to the criteria:

Back the current file

Add another sheet and enter in the first cell (please adjust sheet name  Sheet1 and the range):


=LET(last_cell, XLOOKUP(TRUE, Sheet1!C:C <> "", Sheet1!C:C, , , -1),
data, Sheet1!A2:last_cell, header, Sheet1!A1:C1, threshold, 10 * 1000,
VSTACK(header,
FILTER(data, SUMIFS(INDEX(data, , 3), INDEX(data, , 1), INDEX(data, , 1)) < threshold)))



Select all data in the new sheet and copy

Add another sheet and select Edit > Paste Special… > Values

Delete the other sheets


